# WPF View not hiding main window contents

Tags: wpf, view

I have my main window with a grid (2 rows). Row 0 is bound to a couple of views (showing only relevant xaml code):

```
   <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          //definition of 2 rows
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ContentControl Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding SelectedViewModel}"/>
    
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="40,51,28,0" Width="449">
          //definition of 2 buttons
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

while row 1 contains 2 buttons (let's call them A and B). When I click button A, view A is displayed in row 0, when I click button B, the same happens to view B. Each view is just a page with a different colour, so I can be sure the view is actually displayed. Quite simple.

Now I noted that if I insert a label in row 0:

```
   <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          //definition of 2 rows
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ContentControl Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding SelectedViewModel}"/>
    
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="40,51,28,0" Width="449">
        <Label Name="MyLabel" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="188,172,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="56" Width="135" FontSize="22"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="40,51,28,0" Width="449">
          //definition of 2 buttons
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

the view doesn't cover the label, that remains visible. If I look at the view's properties, its colour is blue and its opacity is set to 100%, so it should cover everything that's displayed on the main window's grid, shouldn't it? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Gianni

Comment: Do you have any styles applied to the ContentControl? You may be manually setting its height, width, horizontal alignment or vertical alignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are could place the `StackPanel` containing the `Label` on top of the `ContentControl` by changing the order in which they are declared:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="449">
        <Label Name="MyLabel" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="56" Width="135" FontSize="22"/>
    </StackPanel>
    
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="0">
        <StackPanel Background="Red" Opacity="1"/>
    </ContentControl>
```

or by setting a value > 0 for the `Panel.ZIndex`:

```
<ContentControl Grid.Row="0" Panel.ZIndex="1">
        <StackPanel Background="Red" Opacity="1"/>
    </ContentControl>
```

[Panel.ZIndex MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.panel.zindex?view=net-5.0)

Please note, it's in Row 0 so it won't cover the contents of Row 1 unless you set `Grid.RowSpan="2"`.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad it helped. Please mark the answer as accepted.